# I am looking for articules about determining beacon distance between two scanners but at distance 15-25 meters

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, rssi

Maybe somebody has some links about determining distance where the scanners are more than 15 meters apart?
All the articles I found describe how to determine the distance, but for example in room 5/5 with 4 scanners or even closer together. I want to know what accuracy can I have when scanners are they are further apart.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately beacon distance estimates are wildly inaccurate at distances over a few meters.  It is nearly impossible to discern between beacons 15 meters and 25 meters away.

Why?  Because radio signals get weaker with distance, and at distances that near the maximum range of Bluetooth beacons (typically 20-40 meters in home/school/office indoor environments with walls and instructions) the signal level nears the noise floor.  There is very little absolute difference between the signal level of a beacon at 25 meters from one at 15 meters.  By looking for such tiny differences in signal you are mostly seeing error and non-distance influences on the signal measurement.

The best you can do with a distance calculation is determine that it is likely the beacon is far away (e.g. > 10 meters).  One you know it is far away determining how far is beyond the limits of the technology.

Comment: I am aware of this. Maybe I didn't make it clear, but I mean a case where 15-25 meters is the total distance between two scanners. So it's practically <10 of the scanners.